# Django rest create function on model with foreign key

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-rest-framework

I am writing my first app in Django and Django Rest Framework. Now I am stuck on a create view. This view has to create a new project for a user.

This is my model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Projects(models.Model):
    """Model containing all the project information."""
    NEW = 'NEW'
    PENDING = 'PENDING'
    OPEN = 'OPEN'
    ACTIVE = 'ACTIVE'
    CLOSED = 'CLOSED'
    DELIVERED = 'DELIVERED'
    PROJECT_STATUS_CHOICES = (
        (NEW, 'New'),
        (PENDING, 'Pending'),
        (OPEN, 'Open'),
        (ACTIVE, 'Active'),
        (CLOSED, 'Closed'),
        (DELIVERED, 'Delivered'),
    )
    project_owner = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='project_owner')
    project_number = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    date = models.DateField(blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=15,
                              choices=PROJECT_STATUS_CHOICES,
                              default=NEW)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    summary = models.TextField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.project_number
```

This is the view for the projects. The list and retrieve functions work. The problem is with the create view shown below:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework import viewsets, status
from rest_framework.response import Response
from userpermissions.views import PhotographerPermission
from projects.models import Projects
from projects.serializers import ProjectSerializer


class ProjectView(viewsets.ViewSet):

    model = Projects
    serializer_class = ProjectSerializer
    permission_classes = (PhotographerPermission,)

    def get_serializer_context(self):
        return {'request': self.request}

    def list(self, request):
        user = request.user
        queryset = Projects.objects.filter(project_owner=user)
        serializer = ProjectSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def retrieve(self, request, project_id=None):
        user = request.user
        queryset = Projects.objects.filter(project_owner=user, id=project_id)
        serializer = ProjectSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def create(self, request):
        serializer = ProjectSerializer(data=request.data, many=True)
        user = User.objects.get(username=request.user)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.project_owner = user.id
            serializer.save()
            return Response({'status': 'done'})
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors,
                            status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Whenever I try to create a project the function returns 'done'. So I think it executed and saved a new project. However the project is not in the database. I am clueless and I don't seem to get various fixes working that I find on the internet.

For reference here is the serializer code:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from projects.models import Projects


class ProjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Projects
        fields = ('project_number', 'date', 'title', 'status', 'slug', 'summary')
        extra_kwargs = {
            'project_owner': {'write_only': True}
        }

    def create(self, validated_data):
        """
        Create and return a new 'Project'.
        """
        return Projects.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

Comment: Have you checked if you serializer's create method is being called?

Comment: I just added:
`serializer.create(serializer.validated_data)` to the create function in the view. The print in the serializers create function is not run though. Doesn't that function executes automatically?

Comment: It seems that when you call serializer.save() it actually updates your Projects and doesn't create a new one. Can you please attach the data that you pass to ProjectSerializer when new Projects instance is not created.

Comment: The data I pass to the serializer are the fields from the Meta class.

Comment: Will it be true to assume that you're using drf-nested-routes ? Doing nested routing for your first djngo rest app isn't an easy lift ... I would suggest to switch to https://github.com/chibisov/drf-extensions; it handles parent queryset more int he spirit of the framework and doesn't require from you to overwrite the basic methods.

Comment: In your specific case, if request.data doesn't contains project_owner, I don't see how serializer.is_valid() will yield true ... project_owner is required by the model / serializer definition.